# Отображение блоков на странице после transform: scale(x,y)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

Делаю preview страниц, которые должны zoom'иться. Проблема в том, что после zoom'а (использую `transform: scale(x,y)`) остаются отступы возле preview, то есть страница не перестраивается. Есть ли способ выстроить их правильно? (на рисунке изобразил что имею в виду).

[image: пример]

```js
var curr_zoom = 1;
$('.zoom-minus').click(function() {
    curr_zoom = curr_zoom - 0.1;
    $('.page-item').css('transform', 'scale(' + curr_zoom + ', ' + curr_zoom + ')');
    return false;
});
```

```css
.page-item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="pages-list">
    <div class="page-item">...</div>
    <div class="page-item">...</div>
    ....
</div>
<a href="#" class="zoom-minus">Zoom-</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делайте zoom не у `.page-item`, а у всего контейнера сразу. `transform: scale(x,y)` не вызывает перерисовку слоев страницы, поэтому так и происходит, как у Вас.

Для большей эстетичности, можно добавить свойство `transform-origin: x, y;`, которое будет говорить, относительно какой точки блока будет происходить трансформация объекта.

```js
var curr_zoom = 1;
$('.zoom-minus').click(function() {
  curr_zoom = curr_zoom - 0.1;
  $('.pages-list').css('transform', 'scale(' + curr_zoom + ', ' + curr_zoom + ')');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.page-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.pages-list {
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="pages-list">
  <div class="page-item">...</div>
  <div class="page-item">...</div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="zoom-minus">Zoom-</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```